# How can I remove an empty space in a footer?

Tags: css, html

In my footer I can't remove the empty space between image and bottom border of footer.

Can anyone help me?
(See snippet for understand the problem)

```css
.news-footer {
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
 position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  
 }

.image-footer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<footer class="news-footer">
<img class="image-footer" src="http://oi66.tinypic.com/wgwbpi.jpg" alt="Download App"/>
</footer>
```

Comment: set the image class display:block; margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:auto;
This make your image also responsive. [ https://jsfiddle.net/wkncsxq9/ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:block`.

> Another method like `flexbox` is not compatible with all browsers.
>
> In IE you need use `-ms` prefix. Learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) or [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.news-footer {
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  
 }

.image-footer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  
}
```

```html
<footer class="news-footer">
<img class="image-footer" src="http://oi66.tinypic.com/wgwbpi.jpg" alt="Download App"/>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex;` on `<footer>`, like:

```
footer {
  display: flex;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.news-footer {
  display: flex;
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
 }

.image-footer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<footer class="news-footer">
<img class="image-footer" src="http://oi66.tinypic.com/wgwbpi.jpg" alt="Download App"/>
</footer>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Set your image with `display: block`.

```css
.news-footer {
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
 position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  
 }

.image-footer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  
}
```

```html
<footer class="news-footer">
<img class="image-footer" src="http://oi66.tinypic.com/wgwbpi.jpg" alt="Download App"/>
</footer>
```